# Custom formatting when exporting to excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How can I set different background color and font for some rows or columns when exporting a pandas DataFrame to Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://pbpython.com/improve-pandas-excel-output.html has examples using [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) to customize the output file:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('fancy.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='report')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['report']

percent_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%',
                                   'bold': True
                                   #, 'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'
                                   })
worksheet.set_column('L:L', 12, percent_fmt)
writer.save()
```